# what is the signal *) means in linux shell

Tags: shell

I do not know what *) means in linux shell, and feel confused
do not kown how to solve it.

[image: here]

Comment: I included the picture for you but seriously: couldn't you just copy and paste those 4 lines in your question? Images are not searchable, you know. Consider taking the [tour] and visit the [help].

Comment: #!/usr/bin/env bash 

cygwin=false
case "`uname`" in
  CYGWIN*) cygwin=true;;
esac

# Enter posix mode for bash
set -o posix

Comment: really, I can not any other thing useful, please

Comment: There is an [edit] link that enables you to fix your post. Don't use comments for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `*)`, the `*` is part of the pattern.
The syntax of a shell `case` statement is:

```
case WORD in
    PATTERN) COMMANDS;;
esac
```

in your case:

- WORD is `` "`uname`" `` : Name of the operating system, like "Linux" or "CYGWIN_NT-5.1".
- PATTERN is `CYGWIN*`:  CYGWIN followed by any number of any characters
- COMMANDS is `cygwin=true`: Set the variable to "true"

So your snippet sets the variable `cygwin` to `true` when the operating system name starts with "CYGWIN".